# Botón Cerrar de Lista de apps recientes

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola que tal? Espero puedan ayudarme, estoy desarrollando una app en Android en la cual creo un login mediante web-services y lo cierro mediante un botón que tengo en mi activity, lo que necesito es cerrar la sesión cuando el usuario por x razón presione la tecla de apps recientes y oprima el boton Limpiar Todo. 
Tengo la idea de programar el botón de cerrar la aplicación cuando se muestran las miniaturas de la lista de apps recientes pero no logro hacerlo, espero sus respuestas y propuestas de antemano muchas gracias.
Anexo una imagen sobre el botón que deseo agregarle el código.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nunca he intentado algo similar en mi experiencia. Lo más cercano fué evaluar si la app fue enviada al background. Pero de todos modos te dejo [Esta respuesta de SO inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33078782/5280677) por si te resulta útil. No sé si funcionará.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, revisare la propuesta y cualquier cosa te comento.